# JavaScript object: access variable property by name as string

Tags: javascript, object

If I have a javascript object that looks like below

```
var columns = {
  left: true,
  center : false,
  right : false
}
```

and I have a function that is passed both the object, and a property name like so

```
//should return false
var side = read_prop(columns, 'right');
```

what would the body of `read_prop(object, property)` look like?

Answer (score 929, accepted):

You don't need a function for it - simply use the [*bracket notation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation):

```
var side = columns['right'];
```

This is equal to [*dot notation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Dot_notation), `var side = columns.right;`, except the fact that `right` could also come from a variable, function return value, etc., when using bracket notation.

If you NEED a function for it, here it is:

```
function read_prop(obj, prop) {
    return obj[prop];
}
```

---

To answer some of the comments below that aren't directly related to the original question, nested objects can be referenced through multiple brackets. If you have a nested object like so:

```
var foo = { a: 1, b: 2, c: {x: 999, y:998, z: 997}};
```

you can access property `x` of `c` as follows:

```
var cx = foo['c']['x']
```

If a property is undefined, an attempt to reference it will return `undefined` (not `null` or `false`):

```
foo['c']['q'] === null
// returns false

foo['c']['q'] === false
// returns false

foo['c']['q'] === undefined
// returns true
```

Comment: Maybe this goes without saying, but I think it might be worth explicitly pointing out `prop` must be of type `string` and or resolve to type `string`.

Comment: IMHO that's quite obvious...

Comment: and what about nested objects?

Comment: What happens if the property does not exist? Does it return undefined?

Comment: @BluE: Wouldn't it have been easier to test? ;) Yes, accessing an *undefined* property returns `undefined`.

Comment: For the answer completeness sake, I believe it's a good idea to add info about non-existing prop and `undefined` to your answer. People asking for this question most likely don't know what will be returned in this case.

Comment: @sarkiroka this has now been answered :)

Comment: Reading up on this subject and getting my head around this topic - but given bracket notations ability to use STRINGS and VARS - is there any use cases or benefits to using dot notation any more?

Comment: dot notation is more readable and shorter. you should always use it unless the key contains characters not allowed outside strings (anything but alphanumeric characters and underscores) or variables.

Comment: works also for classes, exg.: class A{
  wurzel=12;
}

B = new A;

console.log(B['wurzel']);

Comment: @ThiefMaster what if I want obj to be a string as well? Is there no way to do it without using eval?

Answer (score 98):

ThiefMaster's answer is 100% correct, although I came across a similar problem where I needed to fetch a property from a nested object (object within an object), so as an alternative to his answer, you can create a recursive solution that will allow you to define a nomenclature to grab any property, regardless of depth:

```
function fetchFromObject(obj, prop) {

    if(typeof obj === 'undefined') {
        return false;
    }

    var _index = prop.indexOf('.')
    if(_index > -1) {
        return fetchFromObject(obj[prop.substring(0, _index)], prop.substr(_index + 1));
    }

    return obj[prop];
}
```

Where your string reference to a given property ressembles `property1.property2`

Code and comments in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amofb8xa/5/).

Comment: this will not work if `prop` string will contain array indexes

Comment: Such as this? http://jsfiddle.net/amofb8xa/8/

Comment: Accessing nested properties can be done much simpler, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable/30974910#30974910

Answer (score 11):

Since I was helped with my project by the answer above (I asked a duplicate question and was referred here), I am submitting an answer (my test code) for bracket notation when nesting within the var:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function displayFile(whatOption, whatColor) {
      var Test01 = {
        rectangle: {
          red: "RectangleRedFile",
          blue: "RectangleBlueFile"
        },
        square: {
          red: "SquareRedFile",
          blue: "SquareBlueFile"
        }
      };
      var filename = Test01[whatOption][whatColor];
      alert(filename);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p onclick="displayFile('rectangle', 'red')">[ Rec Red ]</p>
  <br/>
  <p onclick="displayFile('square', 'blue')">[ Sq Blue ]</p>
  <br/>
  <p onclick="displayFile('square', 'red')">[ Sq Red ]</p>
</body>
</html>
```