# Getting a Custom Objects properties by string var

Tags: javascript, properties, custom-object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript object, access variable property name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-name)

Trying to get more advanced in my JS...

I have a custom object:

```
Object myObject = new Object();

myObject.thing = anythingHere;
```

I would like to be able to retrieve a custom objects property by passing in a string... eg:

```
var propertyString = 'thing';
alert(myObject.propertyString);
```

I can't quite figure that out. I've looked at a number of tutorials for custom objects - but nothing shows how to get properties that I don't know the names of... Also - I would like to avoid looping through all properties if possible...

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Simply use `myObject['thing']`.

Comment: why myObject.thing does not retrive the value?

Comment: Because in this comment "thing" is a string (its surrounded by quotes).

Comment: if you want something to work for nested objects and you can use lodash something like _.map([object], _.property(propertyPath))[0]; would work.

Comment: @D.B the reason myObject.thing doesn't work is because _thing_ is assumed to be a property on myObject when using 'dot' syntax. To get Javascript to treat _thing_ as a variable, you must use [] syntax.

Answer (score 94):

You could use:

```
myObject[propertyString] ;
```

Comment: why myObject.thing does not retrive the value?

Comment: @D.B Because that notation looks for an attributed named `thing`.