# javascript noob. variables and elements

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

Total noob here with javascript.  I'm trying to alter a function.  This is the one that is currently there and works.

```
function hideStateField(theForm) {
    theForm.state.disabled = true;
    theForm.state.className = 'hiddenField';
    theForm.state.setAttribute('className', 'hiddenField');
    document.getElementById("stateLabel").className = 'hiddenField';
    document.getElementById("stateLabel").setAttribute('className', 'hiddenField');
    document.getElementById("stateText").className = 'hiddenField';
    document.getElementById("stateText").setAttribute('className', 'hiddenField');
    document.getElementById("stateBreak").className = 'hiddenField';
    document.getElementById("stateBreak").setAttribute('className', 'hiddenField');
}
```

I want to make it more generic so its not specific to the "state" field.  So I'm changing the function name to reflect that and adding a 2nd parameter. Then I'm trying to use that 2nd parameter as a variable in place of where we see "state".

```
function hideAddressField(theForm,theField) {
    theForm.theField.disabled = true;
    theForm.theField.className = 'hiddenField';
    theForm.theField.setAttribute('className', 'hiddenField');
    document.getElementById(theField+"Label").className = 'hiddenField';
    document.getElementById(theField+"Label").setAttribute('className', 'hiddenField');
    document.getElementById(theField+"Text").className = 'hiddenField';
    document.getElementById(theField+"Text").setAttribute('className', 'hiddenField');
    document.getElementById(theField+"Break").className = 'hiddenField';
    document.getElementById(theField+"Break").setAttribute('className', 'hiddenField');
}
```

I tested it simply with "state" as the 2nd variable to be sure it worked... and it didn't.  I keep getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of undefined".  I'm sure its a syntax error.  My call to this function is:

```
hideAddressField(theForm,state);
```

The form's name is "theForm" as well so I figured the variable "theForm" was being assigned a value of "theForm" while the variable "theField" was being assigned the value of "state" and the two functions should be equivelant.  Obviously not.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic object property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name) and [javascript object, access variable property name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-name) and definitely others.

Comment: Also the MDN documentation might be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `theForm[theField]` syntax, because "theField" is a variable containing the name of a property, and is not the property itself. Also, you will need to pass `state` as a string.

Comment: Could I get more specifics?  I tried what I think you mean and now I just get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".  NEVERMIND!  My editor auto-did-something and removed a .   I got it now, thanks!   Where does one learn about the various syntax and notations?  I tried Google first and didn't even know what to search for.

Comment: @user1438619: The while MDN JavaScript guide is worth a read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: It will be once Mozilla's website comes back to life :)  I've been trying to install firefox all day so I can get firebug.