# JavaScript call object method by its name

Tags: javascript, object, methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript object, access variable property name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-name)

I'm trying to call a method of an object by its name when certain event happens - here's my code:

```
var imageObject = {
    sendImage : function(obj) {
        "use strict";
        var thisId = obj.attr('id');
        var thisSubmit = obj.attr('data-submit');
        var thisCallback = obj.attr('data-callback');
        var thisUrl = $('#' + obj.attr('data-url')).text();
        new AjaxUpload(thisId, {
            action: thisUrl,
            name: 'thisfile',
            onSubmit: imageObject.thisSubmit,
            onComplete: imageObject.thisCallback
        });
    }
}
```

I would also like to pass the parameters to the submit and callback method.

At the moment nothing happens and I'm sure I'm not calling it right - could anyone explain how to achieve this?

I've also used the following for submit and complete :

```
onSubmit: function(file, extension) {
    imageObject.thisSubmit(file, extension);
},
onComplete: function(file, response) {
    imageObject.thisCallback(file, response);
}
```

But what I get is the error saying :

```
imageObject.thisSubmit is not a function
```

**The attributes only store the name (string) of the method within the object - so it would be for instance 'uploadImage'.**

Comment: is the value of `data-submit` a function or a string?

Comment: @Alnitak `.attr` returns a string without any processing :P

Comment: @Esailija yeah, I was reading it as `.data()`, which can return anything.

Comment: please don't send any more close votes - there are nuances to this question that makes it not a duplicate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TJ's answer is nearly there, except that (per the new code in your question) you need to either copy the arguments from `onSubmit` to `thisSubmit`, or use `.apply()` to copy them for you.

The code below uses the latter method, which avoids having to duplicate the function signature over and over:

```
new AjaxUpload(thisId, {
    action: thisUrl,
    name: 'thisfile',
    onSubmit: function() {
        imageObject[thisSubmit].apply(imageObject, arguments);
    },
    onComplete: function() {
        imageObject[thisCallback].apply(imageObject, arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: What I did was simply this : onSubmit: function(file, extension) {
    imageObject[thisSubmit](file, extension);
   },
   onComplete: function(file, response) {
    imageObject[thisCallback](file, response);
   }

Comment: @SpencerMark yeah, that works, but is what I meant about having to duplicate the function signature.  The `.apply()` method makes the new code completely agnostic to the function signature - it simply never appears in the code.

Comment: @Alnitak - +1, well done for working out what the question is actually asking!

Comment: @SpencerMark - I think this should be the accepted answer. If you accept this instead of mine I'll delete my post.

Comment: @JamesAllardice believe me, it wasn't easy! ;-)  No need to delete your answer, though!

Comment: I tried the .apply() approach, however I'm getting the error saying: 'file is not defined' - where 'file' is one of the arguments.

Comment: @SpencerMark that would imply a problem in the `AjaxUpload` function, then.  Or maybe that we need to set `this` (the first parameter to `.apply`) to be the `imageObject` - I'll edit to show how.

Comment: It might be the problem with the AjaxUpload - it's the external script, but it seem to work when I pass the arguments through the function() and then onto the called method without the use of .apply() - I will accept this answer although it does not resolve my problem.

Comment: @SpencerMark curious - the only fundamentally different thing that `.apply()` does is setting the `this` context.  I'd like to try and figure out why it didn't work exactly as written (although the edited version may work better) but there's not enough code shown to do that.

Comment: Thanks Alnitak - I've tried : onSubmit: function() {
    imageObject[thisSubmit].apply(imageObject, file, extension);
   },
   onComplete: function() {
    imageObject[thisCallback].apply(imageObject, file, response);
   }, but I'm getting the same error. Just to clarify - all arguments should just be separated by coma - they don't need to be inside of array etc?

Comment: @SpencerMark no, you should write it **exactly** the way I did - `arguments` is a special pseudo-array containing the arguments that were passed to the function.  You weren't supposed to replace it with your actual argument list!

Comment: Sorry Alnitak - I misinterpreted this bit - it works fine now with the keyword 'arguments'. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood your question correctly, you need to use the square bracket syntax to access the properties:

```
new AjaxUpload(thisId, {
    action: thisUrl,
    name: 'thisfile',
    onSubmit: function () { //Anonymous function so you can pass arguments
        imageObject[thisSubmit]("myArg"); //Square brackets here
    },
    onComplete: imageObject[thisCallback] //Square brackets here (no arguments)
});
```

Comment: yes, that's reasonable, if those variables are actually strings.  The question is very unclear, though!

Comment: Doesn't address passing arguments into them, however.

Comment: @Alnitak - True. I was assuming `attr` was the jQuery `attr` method, which always returns a string. But actually there is no mention of jQuery, so it could be anything.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Also true, edited.

Comment: Sorry guys - yes, the attribute only stores the name (string) of the method within the object - so it would be for instance 'uploadImage'.

Comment: @SpencerMark I humbly suggest that if your question causes this much confusion, you're probably doing it wrong...

Comment: Thanks James - that seemed to solve the problem - very much appreciate everybody's input!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the `thisSubmit` and `thisCallback` local variables are meant to be the names of the functions that exist on `imageObject`.

Do both call those methods using names from those strings, and pass in arguments, you use a combination of bracketed syntax and closures:

```
var imageObject = {
    sendImage : function(obj) {
        "use strict";
        var thisId = obj.attr('id');
        var thisSubmit = obj.attr('data-submit');
        var thisCallback = obj.attr('data-callback');
        var thisUrl = $('#' + obj.attr('data-url')).text();
        new AjaxUpload(thisId, {
            action: thisUrl,
            name: 'thisfile',
            onSubmit: function() {
                imageObject[thisSubmit](arg, anotherArg, etc);
            },
            onComplete: function() {
                imageObject[thisCallback](arg, anotherArg, etc);
            }
        });
    }
    // Presumably there are more methods here, or added later...
}
```

Comment: Yes - that's exactly what the attributes return and assign to the variables.

Answer (score -1):

you have to use `call` which call a function in js

```
onSubmit: function(file, extension) {
    imageObject.thisSubmit.call(undefined, file,extension);
},
```

see [What is the difference between call and apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply)

Comment: umm, no, you don't.  Given a function reference you only need to use `.call` or `.apply` if you want to change what value `this` has within that function when it's invoked.

Comment: or if you want to supply the arguments as an array (with `.apply`)

Comment: Why not `imageObject.thisSubmit(file,extension)`?

Comment: @FelixKling it would have to be `imageObject[thisSubmit](file, extension)`.

Comment: @Alnitak: Ah yeah, that's actually what I meant :) So the answer is wrong in any regard actually...

Comment: @FelixKling yes, the answer as written is wrong.