# Accessing javascript object with string value

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I don't understand why can't i access values like this:

```
object = {
    test:{
        value: "Hello world"
    }
}

variable = "value";

//this gives me "Hello world"
console.log(object.test.value);

//this gives me undefined error
console.log(object.test.variable);
```

By now i can understand that it can't be done this way, but i still need to give some value to the variable and then use that variable to access object values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic object property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name)

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript object, access variable property name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-name)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
console.log(object.test[variable]);
```

Doing it with dots is using literal attribute names. I.e., `object.test.value` equates to `object.test['value']`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do

```
object.test[variable]
```

Objects can be accessed using both `.` and `[]`.

`object.test.variable` is looking for the literal property "variable", which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is doable by JSON path

For instance: https://jsonpath.com/