# Accessing property of object with variable

Tags: javascript

If I have an object, with properties like name, phone_number, etc...how can I access those in Javascript with a variable?

I want to access the property name in javascript by doing something like this:

```
object {name : "bob", phone_number : "911" }
propertiesArray = ["name","phone_number"];

 object.propertiesArray[0]; // instead of  object.name;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic object property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name) and [javascript object, access variable property name?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4255472/218196) and possibly more...

Comment: Btw, this is not JSON, this is an object literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
object[propertiesArray[0]]
```

This will do the trick. Object attributes can be accessed like array indexes using `[]`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `object[propertiesArray[0]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
object[propertiesArray[0]];
```