# JavaScript: Use variable (argument) as property

Tags: javascript, function, loops, recursion

I'm making a function that will count through data food amount.

```
const countFood = (foodType) => {
  let foodNeeded = 0;

  if (animal.food.type === foodType) {
    foodNeeded += +animal.food.amount;
  };

  const food = foodType;

  if (foodNeeded > (pavilion.food[food] - 1)) return true;

  countFood(foodType);
}

countFood('meat');
```

It's a piece of code in for loop.

I need use this argument to request it like `pavilion.food.meat`

Comment: Not getting this properly.How is `foodType` related to `pavilion.food.meat`? and what does this means `(pavilion.food->>[food]<<- - 1)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing property of object with variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230063/accessing-property-of-object-with-variable)

Comment: Just remove the `->>` and `<<-` because the `[food]` syntax is already correct

Comment: OK. As written there is no question because the code should be working. Do you have any other issue with it apart from the original `I need to use this argument` question that you accidentally answered yourself?

Comment: It works. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access an object property using the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation).

Example:

```js
const pavillon = {
  food: {
    meat: 3
  }
}

function getFood(foodType) {
  const food = pavillon.food[foodType]
  
  console.log(food)
  
  return food
}

getFood('meat');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have:

```
{
  pavilion: {
    food: {
      meat: {...}
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use `pavilion.food['meat']` to reference the inner object.

More generally, `pavilion.food[foodType]`.