# Javascript Objects with variable properties: Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, object, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript object, access variable property name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-name)

I'm sure it can be done but I could use some help...

```
$('.red_button')
    .each(function() {
        var someVariable = $(this).attr('name');
        myObject.someVariable = 0;
    });
```

Many thanks to my saviour!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.red_button')
    .each(function() {
        var someVariable = $(this).attr('name');
        myObject[someVariable] = 0;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use brackets for this:

```
myObject[ someVariable ] = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is called dynamic object properties.  In order to implement this functionality you would use the following syntax:

```
myObject[someVariable] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

that is correct, assuming you have created the `myObject` before using it :

http://jsfiddle.net/73WZ3/1/

Comment: I think you missed the point...

Comment: @CD.. I think I linked to the wrong jsfiddle. It works if you declare the myObject before accessing. What point did I miss ?

Comment: I think the OP meant this: http://jsfiddle.net/kht9P/

Comment: @CD.. doh, http://jsfiddle.net/73WZ3/2/ yeah ok, blame it on monday. Javascript still catches me out, just as I thought I was getting good at it