# Is it possible to make User defined DOM changes in runtime?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript object, access variable property name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-name)

I am messing around with JS, learning a stuff and I am wondering about something...
Say you have a function `aFunc()`, and you accept a string `aFunc(val)`. The value is user defined and is then used to modify the CSS of an element.

**For Example:**

```
function aFunc(val){
    document.getElementById('something').style.val = 'red';
}
```

Say the user entered `borderColor`, it would somehow refrence `borderColor` where `val` is. I do not know how or if this is possible.

**EDIT:**
Please no `eval()` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use this as a base: **[JSBIN- Demo on a Div](http://jsbin.com/uvobif/1/edit)**

```
var type = prompt("style");
var value = prompt("value");
document.body.style[type] = value;
```

Comment: Correct answer! In JavaScript object.val is the same as object['val'] so if you want to use a variable for the attribute name, just use [] instead of ".".

Answer (score 2):

Every object in JavaScript has a method called [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) which takes a string value and will return a Boolean value.

```
var myObj = {
   name: "Josh"
};

myObj.hasOwnProperty("name") === true; //This is true
```

You can use that to test for the presence of a particular property and then use the method stated in [Akhil Sekharan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13984193/11702) to access that property.