# Variable manipulation

Tags: javascript

I have the follow sample code:

```
type = 'Foo';

test = {
    type: {
        'fooVal': 'bar'
    }
}

alert(test.type.fooVal); // Bar
alert(test.Foo.fooVal); // TypeError: teste.Foo is undefined
```

How I can get the second alert to work?

I've tried:

```
test = {
    '"' + type + '"': {
        'fooVal': 'bar'
    }
}
```

But doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript object, access variable property name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-name)

Comment: @jbabey does not seen duplicated..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use bracket notation to do the assignment instead:

```
type = 'Foo';
test = {};
test[type] = {fooVal: 'bar'};
alert(test.Foo.fooVal);
```

You can't use variables as keys when assigning via object notation.

Comment: And when I have a JSON, how I can alert `JsonObject.type.arrayKey`?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an object literal if the key is defined by a variable.

```
type = 'Foo';

test = {};
test[type] = {
  fooVal: 'Bar'
};

alert(test.Foo.fooVal);  // Bar
```

`[]` on objects lets you access a property dynamically, for setting or getting.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a property called `Foo` you have a property called `type`. You need to do something like this:

```
type = 'Foo';

test = {};
test[type] = {
    'fooVal': 'bar'
};

alert(test.type.fooVal); // Bar
alert(test.Foo.fooVal); // TypeError: teste.Foo is undefined
```