# How do I access an object property dynamically using a variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I’m trying to filter data from JSON in JavaScript.

I define a variable `a`. I want the property of whatever value `a` is equal to (not `item.a`). So far I’ve been unable to find a way of doing it.

Everything else is working correctly because when I changed it to a specific entry (item.date for example) it works fine. I cannot figure out the correct syntax.

```
while(i< elements.length){
    var a=elements[i].id;
    if(elements[i].name == 'targetfeild'){
      $(elements[i]).val($.map(result,function(item){var test = elements[i].id;return item.a;}));
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: exact duplicate of [JavaScript object: access variable property by name as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `item[a]`, javascript objects can also be accessed this way.

Comment: Yep that did it, I knew it would be something blindly obvious, now I feel bad for asking. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Spag-bol , No worries, in your defense JS's pseudo-associative-array pattern is fairly non obvious. If this answered your question please mark it answered using the checkmark to the left.