# javascript pass function name as parameter not working with jquery show hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a very very very  simplified example.

I am trying to pass a function name "show" or "hide" as a parameter.

but it wont work , can you please help?

```
if(a==true){
showOrhide (hide);
}else{
showOrhide (show);
}

var showOrhide = function(doThis){
  $("#myDiv").doThis();
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript object: access variable property by name as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would work like this:

```
var showOrhide = function(doThis) {
    $("#myDiv")[doThis]();
};

if(a) {
    showOrhide('hide');
} else {
    showOrhide('show');
}
```

Hoever, it's still extremely ugly. jQuery has a `toggle()` method that accepts a boolean argument which would be much more appropriate:

```
$("#myDiv").toggle(!a);
```

Comment: thanks for the solution - it has nothing to to with toggle but with the concept. thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you want only pass `show` and `hide` functions you could pass only their names and call them in that way:

```
if(a==true){
  showOrhide ('hide');
}else{
  showOrhide ('show');
}

function showOrhide (doThis){
  $("#myDiv")[doThis]();
};
```

Comment: @Neal why do you think so?

Comment: This should work, because of hoisting:  http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Comment: @codename- Hoisting makes sure the variable is declared, but it doesn't hoist the definition (in case of the original answer which had the `var showOrhide = ...`)

Answer (score -2):

Disclaimer : Eval is evil (Quoting comments). Please use it on your own risk. Following answer is just for knowledge purpose. :-)

Another way, using eval.

```
var showOrhide = function(doThis){
  eval("$('#myDiv')." + doThis + "()");
};    

if(false==true){
  showOrhide ('hide');
}else{
  showOrhide ('show');
}
```

Comment: I know the best methods are using `toggle()` and then `$("#myDiv")[doThis]();`. And thats why I started the answer with an Or. I just posted another method to achieve the requirement. and @Juhana : Thanks :-)

Comment: *"thanks I never new this - cool I learned something"* --- and that's why, @Jithin, it's better not to talk about eval without heavy use of  disclaimers because the actual use cases are so far and between that there's a good chance the OP will shoot themselves in the foot using it someplace else.