# Accessing an objects property via a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have an object in Javascript. For example...:

```
vehicle.image.jpg.large = "mylargejpg.jpg";
```

or

```
vehicle.image.jpg.small = "mysmalljpg.jpg";
```

I then have a variable

```
var imageType = "jpg.small";
```

How can I dynamically return the value of that object using the "imageType" variable??

IE: vehicle.image\imageType; or whatever would return "mysmalljpg.jpg"

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript object: access variable property by name as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string) - This has been answered so many times it's ridiculous.

Comment: again, notice that my item is TWO levels deep. It would work with a simple [varname] if it were the next item in the object tree, BUT, I'm trying to go two levels deep via the imageType value

Comment: Well yes, but the answer still involves just applying that basic technique.

Answer (score 4):

You want to traverse your object...

```
// Takes an object and a path to some element and traverses the object
function traverse(obj, path) {
  // split the path into pieces 
  var links = path.split(".");

  // traverse the object - one level at a time 
  for (var x = 0; x < links.length; ++x) 
    obj = obj[links[x]];

  return obj;
}

traverse(vehicle.image, "jpg.small");
```

Comment: very close... here's the corrected code that appears to have worked:
    function traverse(obj, path) {
    var links = path.split(".");
    for (var x = 0; x < links.length; ++x) {
   obj = obj[links[x]];
    }

    return obj;
  }