# How to add Dynamic name to JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dynamic

I tried following code.

```
<script>
var empId = 5;
var selected = {};
selected.empId = true;
console.log(JSON.stringify(selected));
</script>
```

and I got the following result

```
{"empId":true}
```

But I need to show it like `{"5":"true"}`. How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript object: access variable property by name as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the indexer operator

```
selected[empId] = true;
```

To make `true` a string, just use a string.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this :

```
selected[empId] = true;
```