# Getting nested obj value

Tags: javascript, eval

Given the following obj:

```
var inputMapping = {
 nonNestedItem: "someItem here",
 sections: {
   general: "Some general section information" 
 }
};
```

I'm writing a function to `get` that data by passing in a string `"nonNestedItem"` or in the nested case `"sections.general"`. I'm having to use an `eval` and **I was wondering if there was maybe a better way to do this.**

Here is what I have so far and it works okay. But improve!

```
function getNode(name) {
  var n = name.split(".");

  if (n.length === 1) { 
   n = name[0];
  } else { 
    var isValid = true,
        evalStr = 'inputMapping';

    for (var i=0;i<n.length;i++) { 
      evalStr += '["'+ n[i] +'"]';

      if (eval(evalStr) === undefined) {
        isValid = false;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (isValid) { 
      // Do something like return the value 
    }
  }
}
```

[Linky to Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/IJAkUQoR/2/)

Comment: There's no JSON here. Don't confuse JavaScript objects with JSON.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript object: access variable property by name as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string)

Comment: Calm down. Ok its a js object i will remove all references to `json`. A bit nitpicky though. I dont think this is a dupe of that question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function like this

```
var accessString = "sections.general";

console.log(accessString.split(".").reduce(function(previous, current) {
    return previous[current];
}, inputMapping));
```

**Output**

```
Some general section information
```

If your environment doesn't support `reduce`, you can use this recursive version

```
function getNestedItem(currentObject, listOfKeys) {
    if (listOfKeys.length === 0 || !currentObject) {
        return currentObject;
    }
    return getNestedItem(currentObject[listOfKeys[0]], listOfKeys.slice(1));
}
console.log(getNestedItem(inputMapping, "sections.general".split(".")));
```

Comment: Woah!  Clever use of `.reduce()`!

Comment: You can also just shim in `.reduce()` if it doesn't exist: https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `eval()` here.  You can just use `[]` to get values from an object.  Use a temp object to hold the current value, then update it each time you need the next key.

```
function getNode(mapping, name) {
    var n = name.split(".");

    if (n.length === 1) {
        return mapping[name];
    } else {
        var tmp = mapping;
        for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
            tmp = tmp[n[i]];
        }
        return tmp;
    }
}
```