# Javascript $.get return data, dynamic select from data

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic, getjson

I have a `$.get`, which returns data that looks like this:

```
Object 
    filter_afmeting-breedte_cm: Object
        end_value: "200"
        max_value: "200"
        min_value: 0
        start_value: 0
    filter_afmeting-diepte_cm: Object
        end_value: "150"
        max_value: "150"
        min_value: 0
        start_value: 0
```

I can then select for example the `end_value` from `filter_afmeting-breedte_cm` with `data.filter_afmeting-breedte_cm.end_value`. That works. But the problem I have, is that the `filter_afmeting-breedte_cm` part is dynamic. I get these dynamic parts with a each, that looks like this:

```
$(".filter-js-slider").each(function(){
    var filter = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

The var `filter` is for example filled with `filter_afmeting-breedte_cm`. So with that dynamic var called `filter`, I need to select the right values from the `data` array. I tried `data.+filter+.end_value`, but this is not working. But I gives the right idea from what I want to get, I think.

In PHP it would look like this:

```
$filter = "filter_afmeting-breedte_cm"; (which would be dynamic filled)
echo $data[$filter]['min_value'];
```

But how do I get that to work in Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data[String(filter)].end_value`

This is using javascripts ability to access property names by string instead of dot notation (which is obviously also supports).

Please see here: [JavaScript object: access variable property by name as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string) for further information.

Comment: Could you add some additional information along with your answer?

Comment: Thanks it works! I did have to delete the first dot, because that way it doesn't work, but this: `data[String(filter)].end_value` works.