# How can i choose a property with the name of the property in form of a string?

Tags: javascript

I have a class "Imgs" with many different properties. And i have a variable with a string which is the name of 1 property. Now i want to make a loop for an array (pictures) which consists of many "Imgs" and want to use the property from the string.

This shows what i want, but it does not work of course ;/

Edit: Of course there ist a .xyz property for "Imgs" and many others but that doesnt matter for this example.

```
var property = "xyz";

for (i in pictures) {
    if (pictures[i].property) { . . . }
}
```

greetings, I appreciate your help

Comment: you really mean name?? id or class?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string

Comment: sry i had no idea how to search for that (afterward stupid) question :D i tried but failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try bracket notation:

```
var property = "xyz";
for (i in pictures) {
    if (pictures[i][property]) { . . . }
}
```

Bracket notation allows you to access a property by string containing its name.

It's the same you were using to iterate pictures: `pictures[i]`.

Comment: baduum . . . that's it of course :D thx (sry i am still learning and sometimes .. mhh)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the index notation

```
var property = "xyz";

for (i in pictures) {
    if (pictures[i][property]) { . . . }
}
```

or

```
for (i in pictures) {
    if (pictures[i]['xyz']) { . . . }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation):

```
if (pictures[i][property]) { ... }
```