# Using knockout with property names containing ":" (or other special characters)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using knockout data binding to render an editor for a string => string dictionary. However, I'm running into trouble when dictionary keys contain special characters such as colon. Is there a way to "escape" a property name or special character such that knockout will bind properly? For example, the following does not bind properly:

```
<p data-bind="text: foo::bar" />
```

I am using version 2.1.0 of knockout

Comment: Your binding is incorrect should be data-bind= also

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [`$data` to access the currently bound object](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) and from there the [array indexer syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string) to access any of its properties which are containing special characters:

```
<p data-bind="text: $data['foo::bar']" />
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nnu3C/).