# how to pass dynamic column names to observable array

Tags: knockout.js, observable

For example if my loop is as below

```
function test(obsArray,dynamicColumnName){
     var item = obsArray();
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(item, function(data) {
                computedColName = ko.computed(function () {
                    return data.dynamicColumnName();

    });
}
```

How do i pass dynamic columns in loop of array?

I tried the above approach but i get error as `Object doesnt support property or method dynamicColumnName`

Comment: Please post the full code. what is item? is it an array? does the array item have an observable called dynamicColumnName?

Comment: @SherinMathew item is an array. the observable doesnt have property called dynamicColumnName but i am passing valid property via that parameter in function test

Comment: If the array item doesn't have a property, how can you call it like this - data.dynamicColumnName()? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript object: access variable property by name as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string)... javascript 101.

Comment: @JeffMercado so can i write like data.[dynamicColumnName]() ?
can you tell exactly how to write it?

Comment: Assuming `dynamicColumnName` is a string or other appropriate type, then yes most likely. **Try it.**

Comment: you are getting this error because `dynamicColumnName()` is not observable

Comment: @jeffMercado i tried like data.[dynamiccolumnname]()  but it gives me syntax error identifier expected

Comment: @RaheelShan yes dynamicColumn is not observable but i want to access it as property of array

Answer (score 0):

I assunme you want to add computed to each object of array. Each computed should be dependant of name property.

```
var arr = [
    {name:"A",active:true},
    {name:"B",active:true},
    {name:"C",active:true},
]

function test(){
    var self = this

    self.TestData = ko.observableArray([])

    self.LoadData = function(){
        self.TestData(arr)
        self.MakeComputed()
    }

    self.MakeComputed = function(){
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.TestData(),function(data) {
            data.computedColName = ko.computed(function () {
                return data.dynamicColumnName();
            });
        });     
    }
    self.LoadData()
}

ko.applyBindings(new test())
```