# JSON access in loop error

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a json as

```
var days = {mon: 1, tue:1, fri: 1}
```

What I'm trying to do it

```
var dayswithone =[];
['mon','tue','wed','thur','fri'].forEach(function(day){
    if(days.day){
      dayswithone.push(day);

    }
});
```

All i have to do is push days with 1 into array dayswithone. But this is giving me days.day as undefined.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript object: access variable property by name as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string)

Comment: sorry ! yes a duplicate question

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

```
var dayswithone =[];
['mon','tue','wed','thur','fri'].forEach(function(day){
if(days[day]){
  dayswithone.push(day);

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try `days[day]` instead of `days.day`;