# Accessing object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

Please explain, why this code it's not allowed in javascript and how to make it.

```
var p = "inputText";
regError.p
```

This will give me undefined but

```
regError.inputText
```

will give me a correct result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using bracket notation:

```
regError[p]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Answer (score 1):

If you have an object like this

```
var regError = {
    inputText : 'something'
}
```

and you want to access it with a variable, you'll have to use bracket notation

```
var p = "inputText";

var result = regError[p]; // returns "something"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use with bracket notation:

```
regError[p]
```

You can check the difference between them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string)