# Using variable model in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this schema for business_hours:

```
 business_hours: {
        sunday: {closed: {type:Boolean, trim: true},
            timings: [{
                open: {type:Number, default: '', trim: true},
                close: {type:Number, default: '', trim: true}
            }]},
        monday: {closed: {type:Boolean, trim: true},
            timings: [{
                open: {type:Number, default: '', trim: true},
                close: {type:Number, default: '', trim: true}
            }]},
        tuesday: {closed: {type:Boolean, trim: true},
            timings: [{
                open: {type:Number, default: '', trim: true},
                close: {type:Number, default: '', trim: true}
            }]},
        wednesday: {closed: {type:Boolean, trim: true},
            timings: [{
                open: {type:Number, default: '', trim: true},
                close: {type:Number, default: '', trim: true}
            }]},
        thursday: {closed: {type:Boolean, trim: true},
            timings: [{
                open: {type:Number, default: '', trim: true},
                close: {type:Number, default: '', trim: true}
            }]},
        friday: {closed: {type:Boolean, trim: true},
            timings: [{
                open: {type:Number, default: '', trim: true},
                close: {type:Number, default: '', trim: true}
            }]},
        saturday: {closed: {type:Boolean, trim: true},
            timings: [{
                open: {type:Number, default: '', trim: true},
                close: {type:Number, default: '', trim: true}
            }]}
    },
```

I am creating UI for above schema. So I am using ng-repeat for this purpose. I have defined an array week in my controller:

```
 $scope.week = ['Sunday','Monday' ,'Tuesday' ,'Wednesday' ,'Thursday' ,'Friday', 'Saturday'];
```

And HTML code is as follows:

```
<div class="row-fluid span12">
            <small>Timings</small>
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="w in week">

        <div class="row-fluid pushTop10px">
            <div class="row-fluid span4">
                <small>{{w}}</small>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid span8 " >
                <div class="row-fluid span2" style="text-align:center; margin-top:4px;">
                    <small>Open</small>
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid span2">             
                    <select class="span12" ng-model="outlet.business_hours.timings.w.open.hour">
                    <option value="1"><label>00</label></option>
                    <option value="2"><label>01</label></option>
```

This code goes on. Basically there are four things: open hour, open minute, close hour, close minute. w in week is working when I am simply printing it. But when I am using it in model, it doesn't work.
 I have also tried following code:

```
outlet.business_hours.timings.{{w}}.open.hour
outlet.business_hours.timings.week[w].open.hour
outlet.business_hours.timings.week($index).open.hour
```

How can it be done?

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string and don't forget that javascript is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try

```
outlet.business_hours[w].timings[0].open(hour)
```

Where hour is a property in scope

Additionaly, Sunday != sunday ;)

Could you provide more code?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

```
 outlet.business_hours[w].timings[0].open.hour
```

Comment: Not working. Error is "Cannot read property 'open' of undefined"

Comment: Are you sure 'open' is defined?                                  What does {{ outlet.business_hours['sunday'] }} output?

Comment: Have you made changes suggested by @ysf?

Comment: name of the day in variable `w` is capitalized. however, name of days in `business_hours` are lowercase. since javascript is case-sensitive `business_hours['sunday']` is different than `business_hours['Sunday']`. either make `$scope.week` values lowercase  or capitalize property names of `business_hours` object.

Comment: Also, where does `hour` come from? It's not defined in your schema?