# Javascript: How can I select a functions internal properties via it's parameters

Tags: javascript

I have a function that creates a menu, it has some buttons assigned to it and accepts an `args` parameter. Part of the function is a method called `setActiveButton`. When I create a menu I would like to dictate which of the buttons is active by passing in an option `args`.

For example:

```
var createMenu = function (args) {
    this.btnOne = new Button(); // construct a button
    this.btnTwo = new Button();
    this.btnTwo = new Button()

    this.setActiveButton(args.desiredButton); 

    return this;
}

createMenu({ desiredButton: btnTwo });
```

How do I tell `createMenu` to use one of it's buttons via `args`? I can't pass in `{ desiredButton: this.btnTwo }` - because at that point `this.btnTwo` is not defined.

I was thinking about passing in a string and then using conditional statements like this:

```
var createMenu = function (args) {
    var buttonChoice;

    this.btnOne = new Button();
    this.btnTwo = new Button();
    this.btnThree = new Button();

    if (args.desiredButton === "button one") { 
        this.setActiveButton(this.btnOne);  
    }
    if (args.desiredButton === "button two") {  
        this.setActiveButton(this.btnTwo);   
    }
    if (args.desiredButton === "button three") { 
        this.setActiveButton(this.btnThree);  
    }

    return this;
}

createMenu({ desiredButton: "button two" });
```

However, I feel that there should be a cleaner and more succinct way to do this.

What is your suggestion?

Comment: You're duplicating [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string), which duplicates [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable). Use bracket notation.

Comment: I am assuming the code you had provided is a trivial example of what you are trying to achieve, is that correct? Are you constructing the buttons within the `createMenu` function yourself or are the buttons configurable through the `args` parameter that are passed in and then are created on the fly?

Comment: Hi Anthony, that's correct it's a stripped down example of what I'm working on, the buttons are constructed in the `createMenu` function, but they cannot be configured on the fly via 'args', so I need to reference the buttons using an option set on `args` form within the  `createMenu` function. I've updated my answer to make it a little more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just pass the name of the button as a string, and access with brackets.

```
var createMenu = function (args) {
    this.btnOne = new Button(); // construct a button
    this.btnTwo = new Button();
    this.btnTwo = new Button()

    this.setActiveButton(this[args.desiredButton]); // access this[property]

    return this;
}

createMenu({ desiredButton: 'btnTwo' }); // string name of property
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear to me why you are returning an object of properties that have no values, but you could do it like this. In my example I set the properties equal to strings like 'button 1', 'button 2', etc:

```
// pass number of total buttons, index of active button
var createMenu = function (total, active) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
       obj['btn'+(i+1)] = 'button '+(i+1);
    }
    setActiveButton(obj['btn'+active]);
    return obj;
}
```

In your example you reference `setActiveButton` as a property of the function but it isn't defined, so I have referenced it as a separate function.