# Fetch Key value pair from JSON without using .(DOT) in Java script or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to get Data from below JSON without using dot(`.`)?

```
var JsonObj = {
  "database.status" : {
    "healthy" : false,
    "error" : {
      "message" : null,
      "stack" : [ "com.dhrubajyoti.tvs.utilities.DatabaseHealthCheck.check(DatabaseHealthCheck.java:26)", "com.codahale.metrics.health.HealthCheck.execute(HealthCheck.java:172)" ]
    }
  },
  "gs.status" : {
    "healthy" : true
  },
  "last.incremental.import" : {
    "healthy" : false,
    "error" : {
      "message" : null,
      "stack" : [ "org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$SimplePreparedStatementCreator.createPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1436)", "org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:581)", "org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:637)", "org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:666)", "org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:674)", "org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:734)", "com.dhrubajyoti.tvs.dao.IncrementalImportLogDaoImpl.findLatestImport(IncrementalImportLogDaoImpl.java:76)"]
    }
  },
  "last.incremental.update" : {
    "healthy" : false,
    "error" : {
      "message" : null,
      "stack" : [ "org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$SimplePreparedStatementCreator.createPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1436)" ]
    }
  },
  "memory.status" : {
    "healthy" : false,
    "message" : "Used memory 3 GB. Current threshold 0.8315874 is above alarm threshold 0.8"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [] notation, like below. Read up [here for more info.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

```
for (key in JsonObj) {
    alert(key + " is healthy: " + JsonObj[key]["healthy"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are asking. Are you asking how to use bracket notation to specify keys as a string rather than a dot property? [JavaScript object: access variable property by name as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string)