# How Do I Use Dynamic Object Property Names in Spacebars?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

Im trying to display mongodb data in a html page in a meteor application.
Here, 'yyyy' is a dynamic property name in the mongodb document.

```
{{#with pullData}}
 <span>Root Url : {{xxxx.yyyy.zzzz}} </span>
{{/with}}
```

My mongodb document looks like this:

```
    { _id : '......',
      xxxx:{
       yyyy:{
       zzzz: 'sampleData'
    }}}
```

'yyyy' is dynamic -> can be different names of people(for example, John or Jane)

I tried using a helper to construct the "xxxx.John.zzzz" with the appropriate dynamic value and call the helper inside the handlebar but it returns it("xxxx.John.zzzz") as a string.

```
{{#with pullData}}
     <span>Root Url : {{helper}} </span>
    {{/with}}
```

Pls help ! Thank you ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your helper `return this.xxxx['yyyy'].zzzz;`

Basically you need to use [bracket notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4255480/2805154) instead of dot notation to access that sub-object using a variable name.