# Get nested keys via a list of keys to get in sequence

Tags: javascript

Here is some code I have:

```
// "iterable" is a Map
iterable.forEach((definition, schemaKey) => {
  let keyToGet = schemaKey.split('.');
});
```

`keyToGet` contains a list of nested keys I want to get in sorted sequence. That is, if I have a user object,

```
{
  profile: {
    name: { full: "Cat Man" }
  }
}
```

And I want to access `profile.name.full` using `['profile', 'name', full]`. Is this possible to get the value using this list of values?

Comment: `Is this possible to get the value using this list of values?` Yes, of course it is. You'd use the bracket notation to get each property in turn.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript object: access variable property by name as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string) or maybe [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Answer (score 1):

You could do a recursive function that travels down the object if the key is found, finally returning the value if it reaches the end of the array. This returns a -1 if a key is not found:

```js
function getFromArr(obj, arr){
 function travelDown(current,index){
     if(current.hasOwnProperty(arr[index])){
         if(index+1 == arr.length){
             return current[arr[index]]
            }else{
             return travelDown(current[arr[index]], index+1)
            }
        }else{
         return -1;
        }
    }
    return travelDown(obj, 0)
}

var obj ={
  profile: {
    name: { full: "Cat Man" }
  }
}
console.log(getFromArr(obj,["profile", "name", "full"])) // Cat Man
console.log(getFromArr(obj,["profile", "name"])) // {full: "Cat Man"}
console.log(getFromArr(obj,["profile", "name", "nonexistant"])) // -1
```