# How to get a value from an object by its position in another object in Node

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

In a script I've got an object containing several other objects, that all have the same structure. It looks like this:

```
wordlist = {word1: {count:2},
word2: {count:5},
word3: {count:3},
word4: {count:2}}
```

I want to generate an array of just the counts of each word, so it would look like [2, 5, 3, 2].

Is there any way to do this in Node.js?

I would imagine using a for-loop where each iteration goes to the next sub-object, but how would I select the sub-object by its position in the main object?
In an array you can type arrayName[2] to get the third entry in that array, is a similar thing possible with an object?

Comment: I bet it doesn't look like that because that would give you an error. Add `:` between your key/values. Also you shouldn't expect that array order because object keys are unordered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript object: access variable property by name as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate over the keys of a proper object and map the values of `count`.

```js
var wordlist = { word1: { count: 2 }, word2: { count: 5 }, word3: { count: 3 }, word4: { count: 2 } },
    result = Object.keys(wordlist).map(function (k) {
        return wordlist[k].count;
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

ES6 Version

```js
var wordlist = { word1: { count: 2 }, word2: { count: 5 }, word3: { count: 3 }, word4: { count: 2 } },
    result = Object.keys(wordlist).map(k => wordlist[k].count);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this using loadash

_.map(wordlist, function (a) {return a.count;})