# json to split in elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

{
          "name": "Chris",
          "age": "RIP",
          "musketeers": ["Athos", "Aramis", "Porthos", "D'Artagnan"],
          "stooges": [
            { "name": "Moe" },
            { "name": "Larry" },
            { "name": "Curly" }
          ],
          "details": {
            "first": "Michael",
            "last": "Jackson"
          }
        }

**Output should be:**
name :Chris

age :RIP

musketeers:
Athos,Aramis,Porthos,D'Artagnan

stooges:
    name:Moe
    name:Larry
    name:Curly

details:
first :Michael
last:Jackson

Comment: how to split elements in javascript?

Comment: Please refer [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide necessary details

Comment: What exactly is the question? What do you want to split in this data? What have you tried till now?

Comment: i want to get keys and values of this json

Comment: output should be :---
name :Chris

age :RIP

musketeers
Athos,Aramis,Porthos,D'Artagnan

stooges
 name:Moe
 name:Larry
 name:Curly

details
first :Michael
last:Jackson

Comment: Objects has `for..in` loop which gives you `keys` and `object[key]` will give you value. Also if you just wish to access value of a property, you could have found an appropriate answer easily.

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a valid JS object. 
you can get name:`var name=data.name;`
and musketeers

```js
var musketeers = data.musketeers;
for (var i = 0; i < musketeers.length; i++) {
  console.log(musketeers[i]);
}
```

Comment: output should be :-  name :Chris

age :RIP

musketeers
Athos,Aramis,Porthos,D'Artagnan

stooges
 name:Moe
 name:Larry
 name:Curly

details
first :Michael
last:Jackson

Comment: @VikashKumar Instead of spreading vague ideas of what you actually want throughout various comment sections, how about [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38306894/edit) your question and providing all necessary details there?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
var jsonValue={
                "name": "Chris",
                "age": "RIP",
                "musketeers": ["Athos", "Aramis", "Porthos", "Artagnan"],
                "stooges": [
                            { "name": "Moe" },
                            { "name": "Larry" },
                            { "name": "Curly" }
                            ],
                "name details": {
                "first": "Michael",
                "last": "Jackson"
                }
            };
if (!Array.prototype.inArray) {
    Array.prototype.inArray = function(element) {
        return this.indexOf(element) > -1;
    };
}                           
var key,key1,key2,innerdiv = '';
var array = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11'];
//console.log(jsonValue);
for(key in jsonValue){
    if(jsonValue.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if(typeof(jsonValue[key])=='object'){
            //console.log(key);
            innerdiv+="<div>"+key;
            for(key1 in jsonValue[key]){
                if(jsonValue[key].hasOwnProperty(key1)){
                    //console.log();
                    // console.log(key1 + " = " + jsonValue[key][key1]);
                    //console.log(typeof(key1));
                    innerdiv+= "<p>";
                    if(typeof(jsonValue[key][key1]) =='object'){
                        for(key2 in jsonValue[key][key1]){
                            innerdiv+= key2 + " <input type='text' name='"+key2+"' value='"+jsonValue[key][key1][key2]+"'></p>";
                        }
                    }
                    else{

                        if(array.inArray(key1)){
                            innerdiv+= " <input type='text' name='"+key1+"' value='"+jsonValue[key][key1]+"'></p>";
                        }
                        else{
                            innerdiv+= key1 + " <input type='text' name='"+key1+"' value='"+jsonValue[key][key1]+"'></p>";
                        }
                        //console.log('test'+key1+'test');

                    }
                      //console.log("6"+typeof(jsonValue[key][key1]));
                }
            }
            innerdiv+="</div>";
        }
        else{
            innerdiv+= "<p>"+key+" <input type='text' name='"+key+"' value='"+jsonValue[key]+"'></p>";
            //console.log(key + " = " + jsonValue[key]);
        }
    }

} 
//console.log(innerdiv );
document.getElementById("htmlContent").innerHTML = innerdiv;
};

</script>
</head>

<form name="" action="" method="">
        <div id="htmlContent"></div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

use the function JSON.Parse();

Comment: i used but did not get elements

Comment: @VikashKumar your question is missing basic details. Unless you provide them, people will give you answer but based on their interpretation, which may be wrong. So I suggest, you provide these details like, what are you trying to achieve, what have you tried etc. If you can create a JSFiddle, that would be even better.

Comment: output should be 
name :Chris

age :RIP

musketeers
Athos,Aramis,Porthos,D'Artagnan

stooges
 name:Moe
 name:Larry
 name:Curly

details
first :Michael
last:Jackson