# String concatenation in angular 4.0.3

Tags: angular

I want to dynamically fetch the value of an object. Here is the object:

```
myObj = {
person1:{name:"John Doe", age:"46"},
person2:{name:"Peter Deer", age:"36"},
person3:{name:"Ben Boar", age:"21"}
}
```

I have a function to fetch a desired name from the objects. Here's the function:

```
showPersonName(objKey: number) {
console.log(this.myObj + 'person' +objKey.name);
}
```

The result I want if I pass 1 as objKey is to display John Doe, but Visual Studio Code shows

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'number'.
```

Please, what can I do? I've had a hard time with this.

Comment: Provide complete code. Plunker would be helpful.

Comment: What is this number you are trying to pass referring to in your object? Meaning what is this object key 1?? There is no such key in your object.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining

```
fetchMyObj(objKey: number) {
```

`objKey` is a number and how you can search for its `name`

Update 1:

```
showPersonName(objKey: number) {
    console.log(this.myObj.find(obj =>{ return obj.age:objKey}))
}
```

Object format

```
myObj = [{name:"John Doe", age:46},
         {name:"Peter Deer", age:36},
         {name:"Ben Boar", age:21}];
```

**[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/PtGW8RxmFfjU4y7pjS5o?p=preview)**

Comment: To fetch John Doe, it's as easy as
console.log(this.myObj.person1.name);
But I want to fetch it dynamically by being able to pass a number to my function so that I can get name from any person object.

Comment: please put me through cos I'm new to angular.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my! My problem was improper usage of concatenation. I found help here: [JavaScript object: access variable property by name as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string)
I was supposed to use square brackets in my case.

```
console.log(this.myObj['person' + objKey].name);
```

That solved my problem. I'm grateful to you all, (especially @Aravind) for enduring my ignorance.