# How can I use multiple variables name as a object name?

Tags: javascript

How can I use multiple variables name as a object name?

For example,

```
name = 'myname'
age  = '16'
```

Now I need the object name as:
`userObject.myname_16.another_field`

Comment: Could you elaborate more on that? Cause it's not very clear what you're asking for.

Comment: Why would you want that? Can you post some more context? What have you tried?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can try `userObject[name+'_'+age].another_field `

Comment: you can use like this userObject[name +'_'+age][another_field]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access Object properties with square brackets too (bracket notation).

Try the following;

```
userObject[name+'_'+age].another_field
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are exactly looking for.

May be you want to create nested objects.

```js
name = 'myname';
age  = '16';

console.log("Name",name);

var userObject = { name : { city : "NY" }};

console.log(userObject.name.city);
```

```js
name = 'myname';
age  = '16';

var userObject = {};
userObject[name+"_"+age]= "Test";

console.log(userObject.myname_16);
```