# Access JSON data through variable .-string interpolation

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

Trying to access integer stored under id's/keys in json object. Why doesn't this code work on its own?

```
 var rooms = {
    'kitchen': [7, 40, 36, 16],
    'livingroom': 31,
    'livingroom2': 15,
    'livingroom3': 38,
    'gallery': 35,
    'gallery2': 29,
    'gallery3': 12,
    'office': [22, 32],
    'neekonsbedroom': 18,
    'homeworkroom': 33,
    'diningroom': 13,
    'atrium': 11
}
function switchOne(id) {
    console.log(rooms.id)
}
 switchOne('office')
```

`console.log()` returns `undefined`, but simply `console.log(rooms.office)` returns `[ 22, 32 ]`
Any and all help is greatly appreciated!
Happy coding!

Comment: rooms[id] .....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript object: access variable property by name as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the literal key `"id"` within your object, not the key at the value of `id` (i.e. `"office"`). To get Javascript to treat `id` as a variable you need to use `rooms[id]`.

The information here explains (towards the bottom) accessing properties of objects: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp.

Answer (score 3):

You should try this way `object[key]`