# Dynamically access object properties using a variable

Tags: javascript

I have a large object with multiple objects nested within it. I have a function that will take the key of one of the objects, and I want to add a new property to the sub-object that is called. Something like https://jsfiddle.net/cf15xdfm/2/

```
var my_object = {
    object1: {
    key: 'value',
    key2: 'value2'
  },
  object2: {
    key: 'othervalue',
    key2: 'another'
  }
}

function doSomething(obj_key) {
    // add a new property to the object 
  my_object.obj_key.new_prop = 'this_new_prop';
}

doSomething('object1');

console.dir(my_object);
```

How do I reference the variable `obj_key` in the `doSomething` method so that I can alter the desired object?

Comment: Also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of `brackets notation` for accessing `dynamic keys`

```js
var my_object = {
    object1: {
    key: 'value',
    key2: 'value2'
  },
  object2: {
    key: 'othervalue',
    key2: 'another'
  }
}

function doSomething(obj_key) {
    // add a new property to the object 
  my_object[obj_key].new_prop = 'this_new_prop'; // using bracket notation here
}

doSomething('object1');

console.dir(my_object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
my_object[obj_key].new_prop='this_new_prop';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call properties as string like this:

```
obj['property_name']
```

So you should do this:

```
my_object[obj_key].new_prop = 'this_new_prop';
```

Edit: Sorry didn't see the answer was already there