# Javascript form cross reference items

Tags: javascript

I've got a HTML5 form with 2 dropdown inputs.
The form is used to determine the distance between 2 company locations.

The current script works, but its not really good, because this would work for a few locations, but not for 23 locations as it is in my case.

How can I make an "cross reference function" that just checks a long list of vars and values?

## Script:

The javascript function to check the chosen dropdown options and return the value:

`inputField` is the field that shows the distance to the user.

```
function initCalc(inputField,select1,select2) {
         select1.change(function(){
            inputField.val(calculateValue(select1.val(),select2.val()));
        });
        select2.change(function(){
            inputField.val(calculateValue(select1.val(),select2.val()));
        });
    }
```

"Calculating" the distance:

```
function calculateValue(firstOp,secondOp) {
        var kmCost = 0.19;
            if (firstOp == "Company1" && secondOp == "Company1") { var total = 0; }
            else if (firstOp == "Company1" && secondOp == "Company2") { var total = 205; }
            else if (firstOp == "Company1" && secondOp == "Company3") { var total = 174; }
            else if (firstOp == "Company1" && secondOp == "Company4") { var total = 3; }
            else if (firstOp == "Company1" && secondOp == "Company5") { var total = 21; }
            else if (firstOp == "Company1" && secondOp == "Company6") { var total = 129; }
            else if (firstOp == "Company2" && secondOp == "Company1") { var total = 205; }
            else if (firstOp == "Company2" && secondOp == "Company2") { var total = 0; }
            else if (firstOp == "Company2" && secondOp == "Company3") { var total = 11; }
            //etc...

            else { var total = 0; }
            var total = total * kmCost;
            return total.toFixed(2);
}
```

## EDIT

With help of @JRK I came with the following, but I think I'm doing something wrong to get the value of the dropdown list from the object?

```
function calculateValue(firstOp,secondOp) {
    var kmCost = 0.19;
        var myObject = {Amsterdam : {distances : {Paris : 1, NewYork : 2}}, 
                        Paris : {distances : {Amsterdam : 1, NewYork : 3}},
                        NewYork : {distances : {Amsterdam : 2, Paris : 3}}
                    };
        var total = myObject.firstOp.distances.secondOp;

    var total = total * kmCost;
    return total.toFixed(2);
}
```

## EDIT2

I've got it!
Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string).

```
function calculateValue(firstOp,secondOp) {
    var kmCost = 0.19;
        var myObject = {Amsterdam : {distances : {Paris : 1, NewYork : 2}}, 
                        Paris : {distances : {Amsterdam : 1, NewYork : 3}},
                        NewYork : {distances : {Amsterdam : 2, Paris : 3}}
                    };
        var total = myObject[firstOp]['distances'][secondOp];

    var total = total * kmCost;
    return total.toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: How have you worked out the total? Do you have coordinates for the locations? Or are you wanting to keep the calculated distance, but refactor all of the else ifs..?

Comment: @JRK The totals are defined at the and of each `if` rule.

Comment: Sorry, I'm asking whether instead of defining the total for each combination, you rather take the coordinates and work out the distance based on 2 pairs of coordinates, like Company 1 lon - lat with Company 2 lon - lat - it'll avoid all the else ifs, or if want to keep the defined total, then perhaps use an object of companies with distances of others.

Comment: Yes, preferably I want to keep the defined totals. So an object would indeed be better. I'm looking into it now to figure out how to use that in my function.

Comment: Cool, if you need any help then I'll provide a pseudo answer perhaps. But i'd use something like: `{Company1 : {distances : {Company2 : 100, Company3: 100}}}` access like: `myObject.Company1.distances.Company2`

Comment: Okay, I'm going to need some help with that :) If you could help me with a part of the object code and implementation in the `calculateValue` function that would be great! Edit, oh you just did :D

Comment: @JRK I've edited my post, could you check what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Found the solution, see edit2!

Answer (score 0):

I've got it!
Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string).

```
function calculateValue(firstOp,secondOp) {
    var kmCost = 0.19;
        var myObject = {Amsterdam : {distances : {Paris : 1, NewYork : 2}}, 
                        Paris : {distances : {Amsterdam : 1, NewYork : 3}},
                        NewYork : {distances : {Amsterdam : 2, Paris : 3}}
                    };
        var total = myObject[firstOp]['distances'][secondOp];

    var total = total * kmCost;
    return total.toFixed(2);
}
```