# In a JSON file I need to access to an attribute name with ':' in it

Tags: json, react-native

I'm a react-native noob.
I need to read a link inside a JSON field called '*wp:featuredmedia.href*'.
obviusly i can't put the ':' char in the code.

I've tried in this way... but I've no success :(

```
componentDidMount(){
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const id = navigation.getParam('id', );
    //const percorso = 'responseJson.wp:featuredmedia.rendered';
    return fetch('https://www.seisnet.it/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/'+id)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                title: String(responseJson.title.rendered),
                photos: String(responseJson.wp:featuredmedia),
            }, function(){});
        })
        .catch((error) =>{
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
```

**EDIT 1**
this is a section of the json file:

```
// 20190726085445
// https://www.seisnet.it/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1967
  "_links": {
    "self": [
      {
        "href": "https://www.seisnet.it/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1967"
      }
    ],
    "collection": [
      {
        "href": "https://www.seisnet.it/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
      }
    ],
    "about": [
      {
        "href": "https://www.seisnet.it/wp-json/wp/v2/types/post"
      }
    ],
    "wp:featuredmedia": [
      {
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "https://www.seisnet.it/wp-json/wp/v2/media/1971"
      }
    ],
    "wp:attachment": [
      {
        "href": "https://www.seisnet.it/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=1967"
      }
    ],

  }
}
```

the field i've to read contains a link to another json file.

i've tried: `JSONResponse_embedded["wp:featuredmedia"]` and `JSONResponse["wp:featuredmedia"]`. the first give me the error "undefined is not an object" while the second give me nothing in output

Comment: Could you please post sample json response and also expected output?

Comment: `responseJson._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"]` as seen on this question:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/241271/wp-rest-api-details-of-latest-post-including-featured-media-url-in-one-request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `responseJson.wp:featuredmedia`, try `responseJson["wp:featuredmedia"]`

[JavaScript object: access variable property by name as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string)