# How do I access the filelds of an object, with an string that is pointing to direction of value in object

Tags: javascript, object, data-structures, javascript-objects

I'm trying to access a key of an object.
But that isn't working. Can anyone help me out here?

So I've an object and a string that points to the value I've to access inside the object. And that value is two levels down.

```
const obj = { name: 'yash', { hobbies: { sports: ['football', 'tennis']} } };
// this is an example object, I have a string
const item = 'hobbies.sports';
// now I want to access the object with this item
obj[item] // but this isn't working.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript object: access variable property by name as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string)

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable

Comment: @NicoHaase not really.

Comment: What do you mean by "not really"? Please edit your question to contain more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the format of the key ref (item as mentioned) is fixed and is delimited with '.', we can split the keys and then use `reduce` to come up with the result as below -

```js
const obj = { name: 'yash', hobbies: { sports: ['football', 'tennis']} };
const ref = 'hobbies.sports';

const keys = ref.split('.');
const result = keys.reduce((accumulator, x) => accumulator[x], obj);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

A crude solution to your problem:

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'yash',
  hobbies: {
    sports: ['football', 'tennis']
  }
};
// this is an example object, I have a string
const item = 'hobbies.sports';
// now I want to access the object with this item
console.log(eval("obj." + item))
```

Here's a better one that doesn't use `eval`:

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'yash',
  hobbies: {
    sports: ['football', 'tennis']
  }
};
// this is an example object, I have a string
const item = 'hobbies.sports';
// now I want to access the object with this item
output = item.split('.').reduce((acc, el) => acc[el], obj)

console.log(output)
```