# How do I get values from an object using dot notation

Tags: javascript

How do I get values from an object using dot notation when I have a variable that changes.

```
console.log(`${getData}.BUTTON_${item.UUID}`);
// outputs: [object Object].BUTTON_1
```

In the object is a value for BUTTON_1. My item.UUID is a number that will change to a different button number. I need to be able to get the value for the button number

what works

```
console.log(getData.BUTTON_0);
```

My button number will be between 0 and 4 example getData.BUTTON_0, getData.BUTTON_1 ...

currently I need the button number to be a variable however the following does not work

```
console.log(`${getData}.BUTTON_${item.UUID}`);
```

Comment: I would suggest rethinking whatever design pattern is leading you to dynamically created variable names. Maybe make an array of buttons and access them via `button[x]`? or if the uuid is not sequential like that, make buttons an object and give them a property, ie `button.uuid`

Comment: Is there a particular reason you have to use dot notation? I'd use brackets instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JavaScript object: access variable property by name as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#bracket_notation

```
console.log(getData[`BUTTON_${item.UUID}`]);
```