# I'm trying to access a data key that comes from an api, but some of the keys have characters like hyphens, how can I use them in code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

Some of the keys have the format "something-something" and the JS code doesn't allow me to use them that way, I need a way around that

for example, I have this line, where I am resetting a React state

```
data.sprites.official-artwork.front_defaul
```

Comment: see: [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript object: access variable property by name as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string)

Comment: and [Accessing an object property with a dynamically-computed name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/accessing-an-object-property-with-a-dynamically-computed-name)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation).

For your example:

```
data.sprites["official-artwork"].front_defaul
```

Comment: Flag as [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/accessing-an-object-property-with-a-dynamically-computed-name).