# Set class of a <div> element in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to set the class of a  element in a ReactJS Typescript app. I have a variable with the name of the class, but I can't get it to resolve correctly. If I hard code the class name with

```
<div className={styles.myClass}>
```

then it works: but

```
const cname='MyClass';
<div className={`styles.${cname}`}>
```

fails.

I've tried various different approaches, with and without backticks, with and without double braces, but I can't get anything to work. Any ideas/hints/tips?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript object: access variable property by name as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-by-name-as-string)

Comment: @Graeme Burton if you found my answer helpful please consider marking is as the correct answer :)

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem as it's the same solution as suggested by @norbnik, and has the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

One of my co workers came up with the solution:

```
const cn='myClass';
<div className={styles[cn as keyof typeof styles]}>
```

Works perfectly!

Comment: You can also try `const cn = 'myClass' as const;`. It should also work and will be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

`styles.myClass` is the identifier of a variable, so it cannot be replaced with a string with dot notation, like you're trying to do. You can, however, get the field from the object with square bracket notation.

So the solution is:

```
const cname = 'myClass';
<div className={styles[cname]}>
```

Keep in mind that it's case-sensitive (it has to be `myClass` with `m`, not `MyClass` with `M`) and the `styles` object has to exist (so you need to import it if it's defined in another file).

Comment: Sorry, @norbnik, that doesn't fix the problem. The compiler will only accept hard coded class names, ie ```<div className={styles['myClass']}>``` - I get the error message

**Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{readonly container: string; readonly myClass; readonly myOtherClass; }'.ts(7053)**

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is good enough.

you can try these alternative also if needed,

```
const cname = 'MyClass';

<div className={styles[`${cname}`]}>
```

we use `square brackets ([])` to access the property of the styles object using the dynamic class name stored in the `cname` variable. This is a common pattern when you need to dynamically set class names in React with CSS modules