Call .gs function from .html file with function name in a variable
TLDR: I want to call a function that exists in the .gs files, from an .html file, when I only have the function name as a string held by a variable.
Details:
I have a set of functions that retrieve specific output from a database. These exist in the .gs files. Assume for the sake of this question that the function just returns a list of values.
    function Retrieve_Some_DB_Table()
    {
      return ['option1', 'option2', 'option3'];
    }

I have another function in the .html files that dynamically generates drop down elements. This takes several potential inputs (lists, arrays, an SQL query, a named range in a google sheet, or a function name that returns an array). My issue is executing the last option, calling a function within the .gs files using the function name as a string.
There seems to be a bunch of options (this, eval, window, calling a new constructor, etc.), but all of these seem to have a scope limitations. Since the function is not within the html file, or an imported file, the above options do not connect to the proper function in the .gs files
Is there a way to solve this, without moving the function from the .gs files to the .html files (or duplicating them on both sides)? I have a bunch of routine DB calls that I need to make in the backend, so the functions need to exist there, and moving them would not be feasible.

    GenerateDropDownElementHTML()

    function GenerateDropDownElementHTML()
    {

    var settings = {
              contentList: 
              {                
                databaseQueryFunction: 'Retrieve_Some_DB_Table',
              },
            };

     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((ret)=> 
     {
       ret.shift();  
       console.log("ret: " + ret)
     }).this[settings.contentList.databaseQueryFunction]()
    }


Just remove .this

holy cow... why does removing the period work?
I tried "}).settings.contentList.databaseQueryFunction" and it did not work.  Why does "})settings.contentList.databaseQueryFunction" work?

@Chris See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4255480/ That's how bracket notation works. That's the syntax.
